# Docker Ubuntu environment variables

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

During the build stage of my docker images, i would like to set some environment variables automatically for every subsequent "RUN" command.

However, I would like to set these variables from within the docker conatiner, because setting them depends on some internal logic.

Using the dockerfile "ENV" command is not good, because that cannot rely on internal logic. (It cannot rely on a command run inside the docker container)

Normally (if this were not docker) I would set my ~/.profile file. However, docker does not load this file in non-interactive shells.

So at them moment I have to run each docker RUN command with:

```
RUN bash -c "source ~/.profile && do_something_here"
```

However, this is very tedious (and unclean) when I have to repeat this every time I want to run a bash command. Is there some other "profile" file I can use instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting the arg as env like this
`ARG my_env` 
`ENV my_env=${my_env}` 
in Dockerfile,
and pass the 'my_env=prod' in build-args so that you can use the set env for subsequent RUN commands
you can also use `env_file:` option in docker compose yml file in case of a stack deploy

Comment: I explicity stated in my question, that the logic that determines the value of the variables is run inside the container. As such your proposal implies that I need to change the dockerfile from within the conainer? I don't think that's possible...

Comment: the above method is possible and i  have used it ,if you don't have any logic to set the env variables an other method if you have a logic  is  executing  script in `CMD` so everytime you start the container the script gets executed and env's are set according to logic for example to run a tomcat application make a script like `#!/bin/ash or bash your logic script &&  /path/of/tomcat/catalina.sh ` put that script in CMD

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and couldn't find a satisfactory solution. What I did was creating a script that would source the variables, then do the operation. I would then rewrite the `RUN` commands in the *Dockerfile* to use that script instead.

In your case, if you need to run multiple commands, you could create a wrapper that loads the variables, runs the command given as argument, and include that script in the docker image.